# Nested POSIX regular expression character class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, posix, nested, character-class

How do I nest a POSIX-style character class inside another character class?

I'm trying to replace the matching of space or dash:

```
/[\s-]/
```

with

```
/[[[:space:]]-]/
```

And that isn't working. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and the official doc has no examples of nesting. I need the POSIX style because I'm working with UTF-8 and my examples are dumbed down from the actual expressions.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you post some data so we can see original and expected results?

Answer (score 2):

Your third set of [] are not needed.

The [:space:] declaration is only valid inside of a set so you will see it appear as [[:space:]] if it is used by itself. In this case, you have more characters so the following will work.

```
[[:space:]-]
```